# enable disable button on checkbox click jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, submit

On my page, i have a checkbox and a submit button :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbxId" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitId" value="Update" disabled="disabled" />
```

I would like with JQuery :

- the user arrives on the page because he wants to activate his settings: the box isn't checked and the button is disabled.

If the user checks the box, the submit button is enabled. If the user unchecks the box, the submit button is disabled.

- the user arrives on the page because he wants to desactivate his settings: the box is checked and the button is disabled.

If the user unchecks the box, the submit button is enabled. If the user checks the box, the submit button is disabled.

Thank you,

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and what is not working. Also keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a coding service. Also you could be able to find answers to this if you search a bit since this is very normal thing you request

Comment: If you Google you could first search for `jquery checkbox change event.` and then `jquery disable/enable button`

Comment: And think carefully if you really need jquery for this task

Answer (score 0):

You need to add change event for `checkbox`.Like `CheckBoxChange()`.In `CheckboxChange()` event you can enable or disable button.Find below code snippet.

html code

```
<input onChange="CheckBoxChange()" type="checkbox" id="chkbxId" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitId" value="Update" disabled="true" />
```

jQuery code

```
 function CheckBoxChange(){
    let checked = jQuery('#chkbxId').is(':checked'); 
      jQuery("#submitId" ).prop( "disabled", checked );
     
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```js
 $('.checkbox').on('click', function(){
    var checked = $('.checkbox').is(':checked'); 
      $(".submit").prop("disabled", checked);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<input class="submit" type="submit" />
```

Comment: It doesn't work: If user setting is deactivate (box unchecked), the submit button is enabled. If i check the box, the submit is disabled. The user can change his setting whenever he wants. He must have modified the checkbox for the button to be active.

Comment: You need remove to `disabled="true"` attribute from HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (maybe not the best) :

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<input class="submit" type="submit" disabled="" />

$('.checkbox').click(function (){
        if($(".submit").is(':disabled')){
            $(".submit").removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $(".submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
```

Thank you,